# Do I need to initialize bits?

Tags: c++

I have a char and I want to set the 1st bit to 1 and the last bit to 1. I can do this with the following code:

```
char c;
c |= 1 << 0;
c |= 1 << 7;
cout << c;
```

The question is simple: I just set bits 1 and 8 to 1. Do I need to set bits 2-7 to 0 or this is done by default? If I keep the code as it is above, is there any chance of undefined behavior?

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do. Your sentences contradict each other.

Comment: Other bits remain as they were before: If they were undefined before...

Comment: I updated the question to make you understand better

Comment: All the answers are pretty correct, not sure what to chose?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on where the variable is declared:

- if your variable is a **global** or **static** one, it is *automatically initialized to zero* as of the
  ANSI/ISO C specs
- if your variable is **local**, the initial value is **unspecified**.

My 2cents: in this case, you should always initialize the variable to zero:

```
char c = 0;
```

`a` is likely a local variable, so *you will have to do this anyway*. In all circumstances, it won't cost you (almost) anything and you will avoid a nasty bug.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you should first set `c = 0;`.

But instead, you can simply set `c = (1<<0) | (1<<7);`.

**P.S.**: if it's a static variable (local or global), then it is set to 0 by the compiler or the linker.

Answer (score 2):

`1 << 0` means 1 shifted to the left by 0. Which is equal to 1.

`1 << 7` means 1 shifted to the left by 7. Which is equal to 128 (0b10000000).

The current value of `c` is however undefined. So you are setting to 1 the first and last bit of an undefined value. If you intend to have: 0b10000001, you could either set `c = 0` or write `c = (1 << 0) | (1 << 7);`

Comment: How do you know they are "already there"? They could be set to anything.

Comment: The OP is not assigning, he's combining with OR!

Comment: OP's question was unclear, I assumed c was already set properly and he wanted to change the first and last bit.